# Why isn't my pdo mysqli query working correctly from browser, but has correct behavior from Postman?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, pdo

I'm currently working on a project where a user can subscribe on a class event. They have the event displayed in a calendar and when they click on it, there is a mysqli query executed:

```
INSERT INTO conduct_user
         (user_id, conduct_id)
         VALUES
         (?, ?)
```

which subscribes the user for a class event. This works properly with no deviations.

However... When the user clicks a second time on the event, a second query is executed, which should unsubscribe the user from the event:

```
public function unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId)
{
    return "
        DELETE FROM conduct_user
         WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " AND conduct_id = " . $eventId . "
    ";
}
```

The above function returns and assigns a variable $sql:

```
$sql = unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId);
```

It ($sql) in its turn is executed from the connection object $conn:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The strange thing is that whenever I execute this from Postman of Chrome, it works properly without any deviations.

However, when I execute it from the browser, it doesn't execute, even though in both cases "true" is returned.

Here is the repo of the project:
https://github.com/mirchev1977-practical-projects/unity-yoga

and below are the files with annotations to understand how the queries are executed. The steps are enumerated and described. Please follow the links and look for notes which will guide you into the flow of the request process. [UPDATE!!!] Here are the notes on github starting from 0.1, 0.2 ... 
which will guide you through the code:
https://github.com/mirchev1977-practical-projects/unity-yoga/commit/153fa9c4d9907fd1e38f6a2d7d34649b14e3c457#diff-ca9644a4bcedb12a5bbbf1fbf744e496

Here is the relevant code:
file: src/angular/calendar/calendar.js
Here I call the function **unsubscribeEvent(userId, eventId)**:

```
if (indexEvent == -1) {
        eventsSubscribedOn.push(eventId);
        event.attendees.length++;
    } else {
        unsubscribeEvent(userId, eventId);
        event.attendees.length--;
        var inx = eventsSubscribedOn.indexOf(eventId);
        eventsSubscribedOn.splice(inx, 1);
    }
```

In the same file is the function inself.
file: src/angular/calendar/calendar.js

```
function unsubscribeEvent(userId, eventId) {
var request = DbRequester.unsubscribeEvent(userId, eventId,
    CONFIG.SERVER.CALENDAR_CONTROLLER_PATH,
    Helpers.getSessionId(),
    Helpers.getUserRole());

request
.done(function(data) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(data);
    if (data === 'exited') {
        Helpers.logout();
        return;
    }
    // Helpers.setLocalStorage(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(data);
    // Helpers.logout();
});
```

}

It calls the method

```
$dbRequester.unsubscribeEvent = function(userId, eventId, serverPath, sessionId, userRole) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: serverPath,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {submit_type: 'unsubscribe_event',
            user_id: userId,
            event_id: eventId,
            session_id: sessionId,
            user_role: userRole
        }
    });
}
```

from the file  src/angular/db_requester.js .

This method $dbRequester.unsubscribeEvent 
sends an ajax request to the php backend file:
src/server_files/controllers/calendar_controller.php
and its method:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit_type'])
    && $_POST['submit_type'] == 'unsubscribe_event'
    && isset($_POST['user_role'])
    &&  ($_POST['user_role'] == 'admin'
    || $_POST['user_role'] == 'instructor'
    || $_POST['user_role'] == 'user') ) {
    //set session
    // $post_session = $_POST['session_id'];
    // $sessionIsActive = sessionIsActive($post_session, 'not_as_array');
    $sessionIsActive = true;
    //set session
    if ($sessionIsActive != false) {
        $calendar = new CalendarObj(Db::getDb(), new Config());
        $calendar->unsubscribeEvent($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['event_id']);
    } else {
        echo 'exited';
    }
}
```

.

In it is created a CalendarObj
src/server_files/models/calendar/calendar_obj.php and its method

```
public function unsubscribeEvent($userId, $eventId)
{
    $req = new RequesterCalendar();
    //Into the class_conduction
    $conn = $this->db;
    $sql = $req->unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId);
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo 'true';
    }
    return null;
}
```

is called.

In it the object

```
$req = new RequesterCalendar();
```

is created and assigned to the $req variable.

Then

```
$req->unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId)
```

is called:
its code is the following:

```
public function unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId)
{
    return "
        DELETE FROM conduct_user
         WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " AND conduct_id = " . $eventId . "
    ";
}
```

The $sql variable is assigned and the mysqli query executed on the next row:

```
$sql = $req->unsubscribe_from_class_event($userId, $eventId);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Whenever I make this request from Postman
there is no problem.

If I make the request from the browser itself - it does not work.

Comment: You're sharing the backend code but not how you're calling it from your browser or postman. It's better to provide that info here.

Comment: I have updated above, in the description of the problem, the link with the front-end of the process included - from the calendarCtrl of angular.

Comment: please post the (relevant) front-end code **here**. SO questions are supposed to be self-contained. Links can go stale. Also most people will not want to trawl through your entire repo to find and understand the relevant parts.

Comment: @mirchev1977 GitHub was actually down when I posted that comment, and by that I hope you understand the importance of posting all relevant code in the question.

Comment: I updated the problem with more details.

Comment: If, in the browser, you subscribe to an event THEN reload the page and THEN try to unsubscribe, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can only subscribe, but not unsubscribe.

Comment: Have you also verified in the Developer Tools - Network tab that the browser is sending anything and if it is sending something, that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, in both cases, no matter if with the browser or Postman, the result is the same. It verifies that the query has been executed successfully. But, the difference comes from there, that when you check in the database, when the query has been executed from Postman, the record is deleted, but when from the browser - not.

Comment: I fixed the bug. The process was creating the event again after having deleted it. It was a matter of a simple "return" keyword to stop the further execution of the code after deletion.